# How to moderate facebook comments on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

I want to know the methods to moderate the facebook comments on my website. I tried in two methods . Generated code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/ without an app. At that time I used meta tags for adding moderators.

with : `<meta property="fb:moderator" content="FACEBOOK-PROFILE-ID"/>`

and `<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>`

But it didn't work. Then I created an app and generated the code with app id. Again I did't get the moderation options on my site. I need a step by step instructions for making facebook comments moderaion option.

And Here is the code which I generated from facebook comment plugin page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=44869xxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://pixelancer.com/skyper-demo/" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

I googled this problem and got many results. but none of them fixed this bug.

Comment: Having actually same issue. Can not see comments in moderation, even though I have added app ID to the script.